# Run iOS/iPadOS shortcut every 30 minutes

Tags: ios, automation, shortcuts-app

I want to create an automation on my apple devices to run a set of tasks every 30 minutes. Currently, there only seems to be an option to run an automation at a certain time of day.

Is there a way to trigger an iOS shortcut automation to run every 30 minutes? The only way I can think of to make this work is to create 48 automations (One for every 30 minutes) and have them run daily, but I think its easy to understand why that is not really a solution.

Thanks in advance